# Praeparatio in + ablative or accusative?

Tags: grammar-choice, preposition

I would like to know which case follows after the phrase "*praeparatio in*" in the sense of "preparation in (expectation of)" in English, for example.

To use the above-mentioned example, would the correct Latin translation be "*praeparatio in expectatione*" or "*praeparatio in expectationem*"?

Comment: A quick classical corpus search only shows *praeparatio ad + acc.*

Comment: I've found "carnis praeparatio in cura primae materiae Tartarae" and "praeparatio in calidam natura" used by Paracelsus and "praeparatio in homine" used by St. Thomas Aquinas. Unfortunately, I do not understand those quotes, so I cannot judge what is right, wrong or maybe simply Medieval Latin. This is the corresponding Google search to find those quotes: http://bit.ly/2rHPa3u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use the ablative: *in expectatione*. It's not that it comes off of *praeparatio*, though, but rather is part of how *in* works with the ablative. Conceptually, you're "in the state of expectation," which is akin to an ablative of place. You can substitute *praeparatio* for anything else. *Curro in expectatione praemii*, "I run in expectation of a reward."

You prepare *for* something with *ad*. I understand your question implying that there's something to be prepared. More fully, then, you would have *praeparatio ad aliquid in expectatione alicuius*, "preparation for something in expectation of something."

Answer (score 4):

As far as classical Latin is concerned, neither.

I went through the [28 occurrences of *praeparatio* (in any case)](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=praeparatio) in a classical corpus, and I found only one case of "preparation for something" expressed with a preposition:
Cicero, in [*Tusculanae Disputationes* 3.30.9](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/49/59/1767-1778@1#59), uses
*praeparatio ad* + accusative.

It appears to be more common to use genitive.
For example, I would render "preparation for his arrival" as *praeparatio adventūs eius*.
Also *praeparatio ad adventum eius* by analogy to Cicero is fine, but I find no support for *preaparatio in* with either accusative or ablative.
See also the [L&S dictionary entry for *praeparatio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=praeparatio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).

However, this answer only applies to classical Latin.
You commented that *praeparatio in* is indeed found in later authors but I don't know enough of later use to be able to comment on it.

As pointed out by C. M. Weimer in his answer, you can say *praeparatio in expectatione alicuius* for "preparation in expectation of something".
This is not attested, but it appears to be a reasonable extrapolation from known classical material.
However, to me this is not significantly different from *praeparatio ad aliquid*, "preparation for something".
As always, the best choice depends on context.
See his answer for a better discussion of this point.